# How to navigate up from one NavHost to another in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

So I have root navigation graph that contains HomeScreen, which is nothing but a Navigation graph itself, with it's own NavHostController, because in HomeScreen I use bottom navigation bar.

This is RootNavGraph

```
@Composable
fun RootNavigationGraph (navController: NavHostController){
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        route = "root_graph",
        startDestination = Screen.Welcome.route
    ){

        composable(route = Screen.Welcome.route){
            WelcomeScreen(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(route = Screen.Start.route){
            StartScreen(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(
            route = Screen.Home.route
        ){
            HomeScreen()
        }

    }
}
```

here HomeScreen() is with bottom navigation:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController : NavHostController = rememberNavController()){
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { TabBar(navHostController = navController) }
    ) { innerPadding  ->

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ){
            HomeNavGraph(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see it contains another NavHostController, because HomeNavGraph contains NavHost.

now inside this NavHost I have composable from which at certain point I want to navigate up to the RootNavigationGraph's Screen.start.route but can't find a solution to this probelm.

If I try to simply go up (I want to pop everything up from backstack also):

```
navController.navigate(Screen.Start.route)
{
   popUpTo(Screen.Start.route){
      inclusive = true
   }
}
```

it gives me error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that
> matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{
> uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/root_graph } cannot be found in
> the navigation graph NavGraph(0x442b361f) route=home_screen
> startDestination={Destination(0x78cb4ec6) route=MAIN}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different navControllers within the app. One in the RootNavigationGraph and one within the HomeScreen. HomeScreen has the navController defined as a parameter, but isn't passed.

Because you don't pass a navController to the HomeScreen, a new navController is created. This one doesn't have any knowledge of the routes defined in the RootNavigationGraph

You should pass the navController from RootNavigationGraph to the HomeScreen. That would probably fix the issue.

Comment: I have different navController for the HomeNavGraph, since google's official documentation says quote: "Each NavController must be associated with a single NavHost composable"

Comment: That is correct, the thing is, you try to popUp navController1, but the route you try to pupUp, is registered in navController2. You should popUp in the navController that knows about the route

Comment: It works when the correct navController is used but I'm asking myself what happens with the home navController? A new instance of the home navController will be created when navigating to the home screen again. Will be the old one garbage collected or it will lead to a memory leak?